# C# How to display a wait gif over the screen for 5 seconds when i click on the screen

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-3.0, picturebox

hi
How to display a wait gif over the screen for 5 second
i want to show a loading image(Gif) over a picturebox. eg when i click on the picturebox , before load another image into this picturebox my loading image(animation image(gif)) showing on the screen for 3 second and this gif image unvisible then another image load into picturebox.
on the other hand How to display a wait gif until image is fully loaded in c#.net 3.5
please help me
thanks

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `PictureBox.LoadAsync(string url)`.  The PictureBox will then raise

`LoadProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)`

and

`LoadCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)`

events.